# Creating an event for a textbox and AJAX Update Panel Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events

I wanted to create a "Click" event for a textbox in C# (as there isn't any).

So, this way

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "txt1OnClick")
    {
        txt1_Click();
    }

    txt1.Attributes.Add("onclick", this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(txt1, "txt1OnClick"));
}

private void txt1_Click()
{
    ImageMap1.ImageUrl = "guide/1.jpg";
}
```

Then I wanted to load the image without reloading the page.

So I used the AJAX UpdatePanel Control and this worked fine with

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageMap1.ImageUrl = "guide/1.jpg";
}
```

But not with the event I created, because the compiler doesn't identify my new events as 
a real event or something I couldn't figure out.

I added the button1_click event according to Step 8 of "[Refreshing an UpdatePanel Control with an External Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)".

The click event of textbox is not shown in this option:

[image: textbox]

So my question is is there any way to add this event within `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` class or, to make this event visible within the above  option?

So that I can include click event of the textbox within the Triggers of the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create a Click event for a `TextBox`, every time a user clicks your textbox you'll trigger a postback to the server (even to evaluate if you need to do something as part of handling the event). This is very inefficient - you should handle clicks in the browser, using JavaScript and then trigger the UpdatePanel using client-side logic.

This lets you trigger a call to the server if you need it but avoid it when you don't. If you have a server-side event handler, your code will post back to the server (reloading the page) every time the user clicks the `TextBox`.

You can read this link (and others) about using `__doPostBack()` on the client side to trigger an `UpdatePanel` to perform a postback.

http://encosia.com/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/

Comment: What do you mean by "using JavaScript and then trigger the UpdatePanel using client-side logic"??  I need to refersh my update panel from client side, is it possible?? sorry my question does'nt relate, but i think your highness will not mind...

Comment: @AbdulMajid Yes, you can do that. I updated the answer with a link, see that for details.